# Removing extreme values in a dataframe while sorting for multiple columns R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = c(40,9,55,1,2), B = c(12,1345,112,45,789))
mydf
   A    B
1 40   12
2  9 1345
3 55  112
4  1   45
5  2  789
```

I want to retain only 95% of the observations and throw out 5% of the data that have extreme values. First, I calculate how many observations they are:

```
th <- length(mydf$A) * 0.95
```

And then I want to remove all the rows above the `th` (or retain the rows below the `th`, as you wish). I need to sort `mydf` in an ascending order, to remove only those extreme values. I tried several approaches:

```
mydf[order(mydf["A"], mydf["B"]),]
mydf[order(mydf$A,mydf$B),]
mydf[with(mydf, order(A,B)), ]
plyr::arrange(mydf,A,B)
```

but nothing works, so `mydf` is not sorted in ascending order by the two columns at the same time. I looked here [Sort (order) data frame rows by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/sort-order-data-frame-rows-by-multiple-columns) but the most common solutions do not work and I don't get why.

However, if I consider only one column at a time (e.g., `A`), those ordering methods work, but then I don't get how to throw out the extreme values, because this:

```
mydf <- mydf[(order(mydf$A) < th),]
```

removes the second row that has a value of 9, while my intent is to subset mydf retaining only the values below `th`reshold (intended in this case as number of observations, not value).
I can imagine it is something very simple and basic that I am missing... And probably there are nicer `tidyverse` approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *want* `rank` here, but it doesn't work on multiple columns. To work around that, note that `rank(.)` is equivalent to `order(order(.))`:

```r
rank(mydf$A)
# [1] 4 3 5 1 2
order(order(mydf$A))
# [1] 4 3 5 1 2
```

With that, we can `order` on both (all) columns, then order again, then compare the resulting ranks with your `th` value.

```r
mydf[order(do.call(order, mydf)) < th,]
#    A    B
# 1 40   12
# 2  9 1345
# 4  1   45
# 5  2  789
```

This approach benefits from preserving the natural sort of the rows.

If you would prefer to stick with a single call to `order`, then you can reorder them and use `head`:

```r
head(mydf[order(mydf$A, mydf$B),], th)
#    A    B
# 4  1   45
# 5  2  789
# 2  9 1345
# 1 40   12
```

though this does not preserve the original order of rows (which may or may not be important to you).

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible approach

An alternative to your approach would be to use a dplyr ranking function such as `cume_dist()` or `percent_rank()`. These can accept a dataframe as input and return ranks / percentiles based on all columns.

```r
set.seed(13)
dat_all <- data.frame(
  A = sample(1:60, 100, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(1:1500, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
nrow(dat_all)
# 100

dat_95 <- dat_all[cume_dist(dat_all) <= .95, ]
nrow(dat_95)
# 95
```

#### General cautions about quantiles

More generally, keep in mind that defining quantiles is slippery, as there [are multiple possible approaches](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original/Sample+Quantiles.pdf). You'll want to think about what makes the most sense given your goal. As an example, from the [dplyr docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/percent_rank.html):

> `cume_dist(x)` counts the total number of values less than or equal to `x_i`, and divides it by the number of observations.
>
> `percent_rank(x)` counts the total number of values less than `x_i`, and divides it by the number of observations minus `1`.

Some implications of this are that the lowest value is always `1 / nrow()` for `cume_dist()` but `0` for `percent_rank()`, while the highest value is always `1` for both methods. This means different cases might be excluded depending on the method. It also means the code I provided will *always* remove the highest-ranking row, which may or may not match your expectations. (e.g., in a vector with just 5 elements, is the highest value "above the 95th percentile"? It depends on how you define it.)